# Valgrind giving segfault on armv7/ubuntu (32 bit) Docker image

Tags: c++, docker, cross-compiling, valgrind, qemu

I am running a docker container (arm32v7/ubuntu:xenial) on Windows 10 Host and wanted to profile a cross compiled ARMv7 executable on this docker. I installed valgrind using command apt-get install valgrind and the valgrind version installed is 3.15.
I compiled a simple Hello World program on the docker (using the gcc installed on docker) and wanted to try the valgrind working. However as soon as I run valgrind (**valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out**), I get the following error

```
==16972== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16972== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16972== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16972== Command: /root/a.out
==16972==
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

I tried to debug the reason using vgdb and ran the valgrind with arguments--vgdb=yes --vgdb-error =0. While running the gdb I get the following error:

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /root/a.out...
(gdb)  target remote | /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=16972
Remote debugging using | /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=16972
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb: not found
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Connection reset by peer.
(gdb)
```

I am not sure how exactly to proceed and get valgrind working on docker. I found this almost similar unanswered question asked beforehand as well:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3855

The details of qemu used in the docker image is:

```
root@d170b9f5fc84:/# /usr/bin/qemu-system-arm --version
QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.17)
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
root@d170b9f5fc84:/# apt show qemu-system-arm
Package: qemu-system-arm
Version: 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.17
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Source: qemu
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian QEMU Team <pkg-qemu-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 23.7 MB
Provides: qemu-system-aarch64
Depends: libaio1 (>= 0.3.93), libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libbrlapi0.7, libc6 (>= 2.29), libcacard0 (>= 2.2), libepoxy0 (>= 1.3), libfdt1 (>= 1.5.1), libgbm1 (>= 7.11~1), libgcc-s1 (>= 4.7), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.12), libibverbs1 (>= 28), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libncursesw6 (>= 6), libnettle7, libpixman-1-0 (>= 0.30.0), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), librdmacm1 (>= 1.0.15), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg), libseccomp2 (>= 2.1.0), libslirp0 (>= 4.0.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), libtinfo6 (>= 6), libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.22), libusbredirparser1 (>= 0.6), libvirglrenderer1 (>= 0.8.2), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0), qemu-system-common (>> 1:2.12~), qemu-system-data (>> 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.17~)
Recommends: qemu-system-gui (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.17), qemu-utils, ipxe-qemu (>= 1.0.0+git-20131111.c3d1e78-1~), ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms, qemu-efi-aarch64, qemu-efi-arm
Suggests: samba, vde2, qemu-block-extra (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.17)
Homepage: http://www.qemu.org/
Download-Size: 6923 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main armhf Packages
Description: QEMU full system emulation binaries (arm)
```

Comment: You don't say what QEMU version your container is using to run things...

Comment: Added the details of the qemu  in the question. Thankyou for pointing that out.

Comment: QEMU 4.2 is comparatively old; an easy thing to test would be "is newer QEMU any better?" In general though, running valgrind inside QEMU is one complex thing inside another and might still not work even with a newer QEMU.